# Is there a way to have a function run when a session is created or expired?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-session

I am currently planning an application that requires a function to run whenever a session is created and expires. I'm planning on using something like redis but I am open to other ideas. What i am looking for is a n annotation such as @whenexpires and @whencreated. I know that most of the annotations for sessions are at the class, and notthemethod Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Servlet specification 2.3, Java Servlet containers like Apache Tomcat provide the  [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface in order to execute custom logic in the event of created or destroyed sessions. Basic usage:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  }
}
```

Add `MySessionListener` to your `web.xml` or - in case of Spring - declare a Spring bean for it that is detected by Spring. However, Spring is not required as `HttpSessionListener` is part of the Java Servlet spec.

If you go for Spring Session with Redis, you can continue using your `HttpSessionListener` by adding it to the Spring configuration as described in the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-httpsessionlistener).

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public MySessionListener mySessionListener() {
        return new MySessionListener(); 
    }

    // more Redis configuration comes here...
}
```

Moreover, Spring Session comes with support for the "Spring-native" way of event subscription and publishing: [ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html). Depending on the session persistence approach, there are currently up to three events that can be catched by your application:  `SessionExpiredEvent`, `SessionCreatedEvent`, `SessionDestroyedEvent`.

Implement an `EventListener` in order to subscribe to Spring Session events, for example:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.session.events.SessionCreatedEvent;
import org.springframework.session.events.SessionDestroyedEvent;
import org.springframework.session.events.SessionExpiredEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MySessionEventListener {

    @EventListener
    public void sessionDestroyed(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
    }

    @EventListener
    public void sessionCreated(SessionCreatedEvent event) {
    }

    @EventListener
    public void sessionExired(SessionExpiredEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use the component, configuration, or bean anotation?

Comment: @NicholasBegg In Spring, the `@Component ` annotation denotes a class that is supposed to be a Spring-managed component. `@Component` is the most generic stereotype, whereas `@Configuration`, `Repository` or others are specializations. Purpose of all is that Spring is able to automatically detect those classes by scanning the classpath. An implementation of `EventListener`s or `HttpSessionListener`s should be denoted with `@Component`. However, there are use cases in Spring apps where a config class is appropriate to define beans explicitly. Those bean initialization methods require `@Bean`.